# Does every Cauchy sequence converge in $\mathbb{C}$?

Tags: convergence-divergence, metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences

In Theorem 3.11 in Rudin, it says

> In $\mathbb{R}^k$, every Cauchy sequence converges.

But I'm wondering how about in $\mathbb{C}$ or $\mathbb{C}^k$, does every Cauchy sequence still converge? I only learned basic concepts about convergence so haven't been equipped with more proof skills yet. So thank you for explaining!

Comment: Yes, as a metric space, $\mathbb C^k$ is equivalent to $\mathbb R^{2k}$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thank you for prompt reply! Why is $\mathbb{C}^k$ equivalent to $\mathbb{R}^{2k}$? I see that we can represent every complex number by using two real numbers and $i$ but how do we rigorously see the equivalence?

Comment: You just have to work it out. Given two vectors $(z_1,\dots,z_k)$ and $(w_1,\dots,w_k)\in\mathbb C^k$, what is the distance between then? Now if $z_j=a_j+ib_j$ and $w_j=c_j+id_j$ and we look that the vectors $(a_1,b_1,a_2,b_2,\dots,a_k,b_k)$ and $(c_1,d_1,c_2,d_2,\dots,c_k,d_k)$ in $\mathbb R^{2k}$, and  compute the distances, you see that the distances are the same. So this "natural" correspondence between $\mathbb C^k$ and $\mathbb R^{2k}$ preserves distances.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I see! Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The space $\mathbb C^k$ with the usual distance metric is actually equivalent to $\mathbb R^{2k}$ with the usual metric. If $z_j=a_j+ib_j$ for $j=1,\dots,k$ then we can define:

$$f:\mathbb C^k \to\mathbb R^{2k}\; ;\,(z_j)\mapsto (a_1,b_1,a_2,b_2,\dots,a_k,b_k)$$

This has an obvious inverse function $g:\mathbb R^{2k}\to \mathbb C^k$.

This function has the nice property that $d(\mathbf z,\mathbf w)=d(f(\mathbf z),f(\mathbf w))$. So any Cauchy sequence in $\mathbf C^k$ goes to a Cauchy seuence in $\mathbf R^{2k}$, which converges to some vector $\mathbf v\in\mathbb R^{2k}$. Then the original Cauchy sequence converges to $g(\mathbf v)$.

It's just brute force to prove this, but it hinges on the result that:

$$|a+bi-(c+di)|^2 = (a-c)^2 + (b-d)^2.$$

From the point of view of distance, these two spaces are exactly the same.

They are different when you start exploring differentiability in them.